# Jquery hovering over text to make elements toggle

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a table where I want an additional row of information to show up in one column upon mousing over it for 500 milliseconds.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsed').hide();
    $("td#name").hover(function() {
       $(this).children('.collapsed').delay(500).slideToggle(100);
    })
});
```

The jsfiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/846/

Two problems I'm having:
1) Upon toggle, the text in the "Text" column moves downward. I want this to stay where it is, i.e. "Hover over me for info" should continue to be aligned with "Here is some additional text". I've tried adding clear:left, but this doesn't solve the porblem.

2) I've set a delay for the toggle because I don't want the additional info to show until a user has held the mouse there for a length of time... namely, just mousing over the text briefly should not trigger the additional text to show. Using delay however just makes the additional text show up later. This behavior is evident if you just start at the bottom of the table and move your mouse quickly to the top. All the additional info rows show up. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, element IDs are unique, you can only have them once in a valid document. So I changed all instances of `id="name"` to `class="name"` and all instances of `id="small"` to `class="small`.

Second, I used a combination of `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` to create the desired delay, but without "chaining" the delays.

Finally, `slideToggle()` (as well as the related `slideUp` and `slideDown`) seemed to be causing a problem, so I replaced that with `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.  I believe that this results in the desired behavior, but let me know if it doesn't.

**HTML**

```
<table class="listings"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th class="star"><span title="Save listing to favorites">&#9734;</span></th> 
            <th colspan="3">Description</th> 
            <th colspan="2">Text</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 

    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td class="star"><span title="Save listing to favorites">&#9734;</span></td> 

            <td class="name" colspan="3">Hover over me for more info.
                <span class="collapsed">Here is some hovered over text.</span> 
            </td> 
            <td class="small" colspan="2">Here is additional text.</td>
        </tr> 

         <tr> 
            <td class="star"><span title="Save listing to favorites">&#9734;</span></td> 

            <td class="name" colspan="3">Hover over me for more info.
                <span class="collapsed">Here is some hovered over text.</span> 
            </td> 
            <td class="small" colspan="2">Here is additional text.</td>
        </tr> 

         <tr> 
            <td class="star"><span title="Save listing to favorites">&#9734;</span></td> 

            <td class="name" colspan="3">Hover over me for more info.
                <span class="collapsed">Here is some hovered over text.</span> 
            </td> 
            <td class="small" colspan="2">Here is additional text.</td>
        </tr> 

    </tbody> 
</table>
```

**CSS** (just a small change to reflect the change from ids to classes)

```
div.left-and-right {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:5%;
    width:90%;
    min-height:300px;
}

.listings {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid #E18728;
    font-size:1em;
}

.listings td {
    padding:5px 10px;
    text-align:left;
}

.listings th {
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:0px 10px;
    background-color:#E18728;
    text-align:left;
}

.listings tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#F6F6F6;
    border-top:1px solid #EAE8E8;
    border-bottom:1px solid #EAE8E8;
}
td.small {
    font-size:0.8em;
    padding-top:8px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.star {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px;
}

.collapsed{
    display:block;
    margin-top:40px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var timeoutID;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsed').hide();

    $("td.name").hover(
        function(){
            thisThing = $(this);
            timeoutID = setTimeout(function(thisThingHere){
                thisThingHere.children('.collapsed').fadeIn(100);
            }, 500, thisThing);},
        function(){
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            $(this).children('.collapsed').fadeOut(100);
        }
    );      
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sDkfW/)